# Doubt in Subject verb agreement

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, syntax

I have a doubt in the following question:

> Shakespeare is one of the greatest dramatists that ____ ever lived.

I want to know what will complete the sentence.

Comment: What doubt do you have?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It may not be a hard question, but it seems to me a legitimate one, particularly given the use of "that" instead of "who." The latter word makes clear that we must look to two possible human antecedents, one singular and one plural. Plus, an auxiliary verb is not in fact needed.

Comment: Your use of the gap notation '___ ' between "that" and "ever" implies that you think something is missing in that location, but there isn't. It's complete as it is. There is no subject-verb agreement issue. Unless you're asking about the fact that this is a _that_ relative, where gap represents the covert presence of the relativised element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, nothing is needed to complete the sentence.

> Shakespeare is one of the greatest dramatists who ever lived

is perfectly grammatical

Second, to give emphasis to the "ever", it is also grammatical and probably more common  to say

> Shakespeare is one of the greatest dramatists who have ever lived

The use of "have" makes clear that "who" refers to "dramatists. This follows the general rule in English that modifiers of nouns and adjectives should be in relatively close proximity to what is being modified. More importantly it is the only meaning that makes any sense: "The Shakespeare ... who has ever lived" is simply bizarre.

Third, these last paragraphs are about style rather than grammar and so are personal opinion.

"What" and "which" generally refer to non-human objects whereas "who" and "whom" refer to humans. You will of course be understood if you disregard that usage so it is not really an issue of grammar, but people with a good ear for British or American English may find it a bit odd if you do disregard it.

Furthermore, the whole clause about "ever lived" is redundant and rather silly. Is there any question about comparing Shakespeare to dramatists who never even existed? I suspect that the real thought behind this sentence is

> Shakespeare is one of the greatest dramatists of all time

However, it may be that the thought was cultural rather than temporal, in which case

> Shakespeare is one of the world's greatest dramatists

is a much clearer expression of the intended thought.

One thing about thinking about style is that it often forces us to consider more exactly what we mean.